# How do I convert values stored in an object to an array

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
   class Sub extends DatabaseObject {

  protected static $table_name="subs";
  protected static $db_fields=array('id', 'product_id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8', 'col9', 'col10', 'col11', 'col12');

  public $id;
  public $product_id;
  public $col1;
  public $col2;
  public $col3;
  public $col4;
  public $col5;
  public $col6;
  public $col7;
  public $col8;
  public $col9;
  public $col10;
  public $col11;
  public $col12;
```

My `find_subs_on($product_id)` function calls another function that passes values into the public variables above.

My problem is that I want to display the values above in a table, with each col inside a `<td>`

Do I create a function inside the class that takes those values and returns an array, and then i foreach the array?

Do I create an array in the view, and pass in `$sub->col1`, `$sub->col2` etc.?

I would love if someone could point to an example of the correct way to do this. Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you need: [get_object_vars($object)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Note: will export only public and set variables

Comment: Sounds good, but do I put that in the view - or in the class? Right now I am trying to do this:
`
public function cols(){
   
   return self::get_object_vars();
   
  }`

Comment: should be `return get_object_vars($this);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use foreach on an object but if you want to you can typecast an object to an array:

```
 $obj = new ClassName;
 $obj_to_array = (array) $obj;
 print_r($obj_to_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  class test
  {
      function get_variable($var)
      {
          return $this->$var;
      }

      function set_variable($var, $value)
      {
          private $this->$var = $value
      }
  }

  $test = new test;
  $test->set_variable("foo", "bar");
  $variable = $test->get_variable("foo");
?>
```

or easier, but bad

```
<?php
  class test
  {
  }

  $test = new test;
  $test->foo = bar;
  $variable = $test->foo;
?>
```